# Camunda/JBOSS with MySQL

Tags: mysql, jboss, docker, camunda

I want to give my Docker Container with Camunda and JBOSS access to my MySQL Database that is on AWS RDS.

Do I need to configure the file: ./standalone/configuration/standalone.xml inside my container or is it possible to give my container access to my MySQL DB by typing something like this:

```
docker run -d --name camunda -p 8080:8080 \
           -e DB_DRIVER=org.mysql.Driver \
           -e DB_URL=jdbc:mysql://mysql-mycamunda.somebla.location.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/process-engine \
           -e DB_USERNAME=camunda \
           -e DB_PASSWORD=camunda \
           camunda/camunda-bpm-platform:latest
```

Any help is really aporeciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this [environment variables](https://github.com/camunda/docker-camunda-bpm-platform#environment-variables) to configure the basic properties like driver, url, username and password. The container will adjust the standalone.xml on startup based on these values. If you want to configure additional properties you have to link an own standalone.xml into the container. So if you don't want to configure something else the environment variables are enough. Just make sure your RDS instance is reachable from the node which runs Camunda.

Comment: How can we add standalone.xml to the existing camunda docker container?